# How to get handson table data in json format with column header as key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handsontable

I have handsontable and I want to get data enter on handsontable cell into server side.  I have tried to ran below code but data is not in expected format. I was expecting to get the data in pure json format as column header as key.

Html code

```
<div class="handsontable" id="example"></div>
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="submitForm()" />
```

code for creating the handsontable

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#example').handsontable({
           startRows: 2,
           startCols: 2,
            rowHeaders: true,
            colHeaders: true,
            contextMenu: true,
       });
   });
```

code for extracting the information from handsontable

```
   function submitForm(){
        var $container = $('#example');
        var htContents = JSON.stringify($container.handsontable('getData'));
        alert(htContents);
    }
```

Currently handsontable has 2 rows and 2 column. Now if I press the button with cell value (1,1)=11,(1,2)=12,(2,1)=21 and (2,2)=22, result I am getting is in alert window

```
[["11","12"],["21","22"]]
```

But result I am expecting is

```
 [{"A":"11","B":"12"},{"A":"21","B":"22"}]
```

where A and B is column header.

Answer (score 16):

For others who didn't discover the answer immediately, see @hakuna1811's comment above that since version 0.20.0 of Handsontable the **`.getSourceData()`** call should be used instead if you want to get your data back in the same format as you provided it - for example as an array of objects. It is not clear why the `.getData()` call's behavior was modified and it is not explained in the related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2982) noted in @hakuna1811's comment, but at least we have a working solution - thanks again to @hakuna1811 for the answer - it saved a lot of hunting around!

Answer (score 5):

That's great that you're expecting that, but that's just not how that function works :P

Here's what you actually want:

For starters, you don't show us where you set the `data` option. If you look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zekedroid/y5Lavy7m/1/), I use the different notation to generate a Handsontable object which allows me to specify the format of `data`.

If `data` is given how I show it, as an array of row Objects, where each Object is in the format you describe, then the hot1.getData() method returns what you expect.

As it stands, I have no idea what data format you're using so either adopt this way of instantiating HOT or show us how you're doing it.

Good luck!

Comment: when page is render to the user, I am displaying blank on all cells. Even in the blank cell, we need to specify the data format? If so how we can do that?

Comment: kind of, yes. You'll have to specify the data but you can just give them blank values

Comment: since version 0.20.0, we should use `.getSourceData()` to get object, instead of `.getData`, details in [github issue](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/2982)

Comment: @hakuna1811 you should add this as a separate answer. Took too long for me to find your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need mapping the result. let's assume `htContents` is variable which contains `[["11","12"],["21","22"]]`

```
function buildObject(data) {
    return {
         'A': data[0], 
         'B': data[1]
    };
}
var newResult = htContents.map(buildObject); // newResult must be expected data
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getSourceData()` method returns the desired format, but will not reflect the correct row and column order as seen on screen. The following typescript code works for me:

```js
protected getVisualTableData(): object[] {
    const tableData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.hot.countRows(); i++) {
        tableData.push(this.visualObjectRow(i));
    }
    return tableData;
}

protected visualObjectRow(row: number): object {
    const obj = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < this.hot.countCols(); i++) {
        obj[this.hot.colToProp(i)] = this.hot.getDataAtCell(row, i);
    }
    return obj;
}
```